# How to query form library in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

In [MOSS 2007](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SharePoint_Server#MOSS_2007) we use a [CAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_Application_Markup_Language) query to query the SharePoint list and in SharePoint 2010 I found the newly introduced LINQ to SharePoint (where using SPMetal utility we generate a data context class) which works fine for a SharePoint list but how do I query a form library were most of the fields are promoted to it from the [Infopath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_InfoPath) form?

Comment: Not sure I understand what the problem is. Don't the promoted fields act like normal SharePoint columns? I havent tried running SPMetal on a form library but I assume it should work the same as a regular list. Does it not?

Comment: Tundey, Yes using Linq to Sharepoint i am not able to query Form Library. The class generated by SPMetal utility does not create an object which can be queried by Linq.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest use [LINQ To XML](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2009/05/06/using-linq-to-xml-to-access-the-data-of-a-form-saved-to-a-form-library-in-a-workflow.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Ashutosh for the reply, but the link you suggested show how to convert the single infopath form retrieved from the workflow property and query it usign Linq to XML. What i am looking for is to Query the entire Form Library based on certain form library field as my query parameter. E.g. Get all the Employees from the EmployeeFormLibrary where Employee Department is 'xyz'.  I know it is achievable directly by writing CAML query but is not there a way where i can do it using LINQ ?